# JAWS does not read heading inside a button in its heading list (INS + F6)

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, jaws-screen-reader, nvda

I have this code and I want that JAWS will recognize my **h3** in his heading list (INS + F6).
If I change **md-button** to **a** it will works but I still need it with **md-button**. (also happens with **button** att).
I had the same issue with NVDA but removing **aria-label** was solve the problem but not for JAWS.

```
<md-button>
    <div layout="row" layout-align="start center">
        <h3>
            <span>Some text</span>
        </h3>
    </div>
</md-button>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with a `h3` inside a button? As in the answer below an `h3` is not valid in a button but if you let me know why you did that I may be able to offer an alternative solution.

Comment: I have a list via **ng-repeat**  (kind of drop-down list - if I was able to attach a screenshot I would), each header of that list is clickable **h3** and by that, you can expand/collapse that list.

Comment: put the button within the `h3` and then restyle it as needed. That will work as expected and be semantically correct. Your alternative would be to make the `h3` clickable via a mouse click only and then use a visually hidden button for screen readers. Don't forget to use `aria-expanded` and `aria-controls`. If you need more info / example let me know and I will do one tomorrow for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not valid HTML to have a heading inside a button. Inline elements may not contain block-level elements

It's likely that either:

- The browser is stripping the heading tag, leaving a bare button, or
- JAWS simply doesn't recognize the heading because it doesn't expect to find one in a button